# What is the recommended way to deal with POST requests with domain.com to www.domain.com redirection set up

Tags: apache, redirect, post, reverse-proxy, server-administration

I have domain.com to www.domain.com redirection set up, and all the requests to domain.com/ are redirected to www.domain.com/. The problem we face is with POST requests from third party services to domain.com, which during the redirection to www.domain.com, get converted to a GET requests and the parameters go missing.

I can work around this problem by using a reverse proxy setup to serve all the POST requests to domain.com. But is that the recommended approach?

This must be a common problem, faced by anyone who has set up domain.com to www.domain.com redirection. I would like to know about the possible solutions, and which is the recommended and most widely used approach.

Comment: How have you setup redirection? In my case ( via `.htaccess` ) POST requests are kept untouched (as in, the code behind it sees the request with all params ).

Comment: We put the rewrite rules in apache config.